# Python (GTK) : Can someone explain the difference between TreeStore, Listmodel and all the rest?

Tags: python, postgresql, gtk

I'm trying to get my head around the following concepts but all the documentation I've read bundles the whole lot in together without explaining what any of them really are and as a result I don't know how to use any of them properly. If someone could give some kind of real-world analogy that would help hugely.

TreeView
ListView (is this even a thing?)
TreeStore
ListStore
TreeModel
TreeIter

My ultimate goal is to read a set of results from a database and display them on a widget as clickable items. I've got the lookup and retrieval parts down but passing the results back, displaying them and getting them to update is proving a lot more tricky.

**update:**
The following is meant to read the results from a postgreSQL DB and put it into a 'container' from whence I can assign the results to an output dialog:

```
result = self.lookup_player(search) # this returns a result of cur.fetchall
    print result # just to make sure it returns the right things
    if len(result) > 0:  # make sure there are results
       for i in range(0, len(result)): # i used treeiter to see what it did
        treeiter=store.append([result[i][0],result[i][1],str(result[i][4])])
        print result[i][0],result[i][1],result[i][2],result[i][3],result[i][4],result[i][5],result[i][6],result[i][7],result[i][8],result[i][9],result[i][10]
    else:
       print "No players found"
```

I've used a ListStore in the above as it seemed like the best fit. But maybe I should have used a Treestore, or a simple list, or an array...
It's easy to see what a string is, or an integer, a float, but what do these list/tree/model/stores actually look like or do?

I had to give up coding in C years ago as I just could not get my head around what a polymorphic linked list was and I desperately want to avoid the same fate with python this time around.

Comment: How much experience do you have with SQL? This will determine how I write my answer.

Comment: Have you worked through the [Tree View Widget](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html) chapter in the PyGTK Tutorial? Although there's quite a lot of information there, I admit that some of it isn't explained well, but it's certainly a better learning resource than trying to figure out TreeViews et al from the PyGtk reference docs. However, I found experimenting with the various examples in the tutorial helpful.

Comment: Your question in its current state is probably a bit too broad to be suitable for SO. But if in the process of trying to understand this topic you have a more specific question that you can illustrate with your own example code (preferably a self-contained runnable example) that would make a great question here.

Comment: `TreeView` is a concrete class that displays the contents of `TreeModel`, which is an interface. `TreeStore` and `ListStore` are concrete classes that implement the `TreeStore` interface. `TreeIter` is an iterator (in the C++ safe-pointer sense) that points to a location inside a `TreeModel` instance.

Comment: I've read through the documentation on pygtk and readthedocs.org and my confusion comes from there. User4815162342's comment, which I appreciate, is exactly the kind of explanation I _can't_ grasp, sorry!
I'm comfortable with SQL and this question relates to SQL queries so I'm editing the original question to try make it more clear and suitable. Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: Last question: which Python GTK+ bindings and what version of GTK+ are you using? Preferably provide `import` statements... Thanks.

Comment: python 2.7 with GTK 3.12
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import PixbufLoader
import urllib2
import psycopg2
import sys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the right idea with your GtkListStore code above: it's a data store that works very similarly to an SQL table. In fact, you'll find tha the GtkTreeView infrastructure works like SQL tables. Your `Gtk.ListStore()` constructor call maps directly to `CREATE TABLE` and your `append()` call maps directly to `INSERT ROW`.

The important thing to note is that the columns in your GtkListStore are numbered from left to right, starting at 0, rather than named. This will be important in a bit.

The difference between GtkListStore and GtkTreeStore is that the latter allows you to have rows as children of other rows, like a folder tree in a file browser would. The children rows have to have the same column format as the parent rows.

Both GtkListStore and GtkTreeStore are *implementations* of GtkTreeModel, which is an *interface*. From what I've been told, Python doesn't have an immediate concept like interfaces, so just imagine an interface as an abstract base class where there are no default implementations and every function must be defined. GtkTreeModel specifies methods which allows a GtkTreeView to display the data on screen.

So the only question now is how do you connect a GtkTreeView to a GtkTreeModel/GtkListStore/GtkTreeStore?

As you remember from SQL, each column of a table has a specific data type. With GtkTreView, all cells in a column have the same *cell renderer*. The cell renderer draws text, pictures, checkboxes, etc., using GObject *properties*. You've likely used properties already: `text` is a property on GtkLabels, `active` is a property on GtkCheckButtons, etc. Cell renderers have properties that not only specify what data to draw, but also how to draw it.

When you supply the "attributes" (in the function name) to a GtkTreeViewColumn (the representation of a single column in a GtkTreeView), you give the function you call to do the supplying two things: the cell renderer itself and a list of attribute-column number pairs.

For instance, let's say you want column 0 of the table model to provide the text for the first column. Here's how you would create the column:

```
renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()            # create a text cell renderer
column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column")        # create the column
column.pack_start(renderer, True)            # load the renderer...
column.add_attribute(renderer, "text", 0)    # ...and tell it to get its text from the first column of the model
```

Now all that's left is to add the columns to the GtkTreeView and to set your GtkListStore as the GtkTreeView's model (with `set_model()`). If all goes well, you should see your data in the GtkTreeView.

---

GtkTreeView doesn't provide its own scrollbars. Be sure to put your GtkTreeView in a GtkScrolledWindow to get them.

There is a GtkListBox, but it's entirely unrelated to this.

Hopefully this helps clear things up! If not, feel free to point out what you don't understand and I'll amend this answer accordingly.

---

**Update**: In response to your comment asking why GtkTreeView works like this, rather than managing all the data itself and just having functions like `add_row()` and `set_cell_value()`. There are a few advantages to this design:

- It makes GtkTreeView's own code simpler and more extensible in the future.
- It allows people with special needs to implement their own GtkTreeModel to use as the data store. For example, someone writing a sufficiently advanced or memory-hungry program can create a GtkTreeModel that communicates directly with the SQL database, avoiding the need to copy data everywhere.
- It allows the same data store to be used by multiple instances of GtkTreeView.
- It allows the same data store to be used by other widgets. [GtkIconView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkIconView.html) is another widget that uses GtkTreeModel to store its data (and it also uses cell renderers to render the data).

Comment: I really appreciate this. you've put a lot of effort into it and most of what I read makes sense. I'm still a bit unsure about the order of how things are passed and why, so I'll try put down what I know and mark what I don't know.

I get my rows of data from the database, each of a type defined by the DB stucture.
I pass this information, row by row, into a ListStore which also has types for each element defined previously. Question here: how do I handle a DB column which is an int array? liststore doesn't seem to accept arrays as elements?

Comment: I then call upon the Treemodel and ask it to give that info to the TreeView. It's not clear to me why this step needs to happen. Why is it not possible to give the list information directly to the treeview and get it to display it according to its defined layout?
The TreeView itself seems straightforward - it's the physical implementation of what goes where and what it should look like.

Comment: OK, it's taken me forever to see what now seems blindingly obvious - a ListStore _is_ a TreeModel

Comment: Oh, I thought I mentioned that... if I didn't then I'll change the text :/ As for the first question, what does the int array represent and how do you want it displayed to the user? I'll add the answer to the second question shortly.

Comment: You did, several times, it just did not sink in for some reason. The database is of a set of players and the int array in question is the list of positions each player plays. It has a minimum of one element and often up to four. I'm getting somewhere now, figuring out how to display the data in a tree in a scrollbox and make the elements, or a button beside each, clickable

Comment: Hm... I'm still not sure how you would want to display that to the user. Do you have any idea of what you want to show them or how they are to interface with the data?

Comment: it's a simple search and display - user enters text in an Entry box, database is queried and matching records are returned. Two of the fields are displayed (last and first name) in a box alongside a button which, when clicked, displays full results in a bigger box beside it. In the case of the positions, it should just display them as a list- Positon: forward, back, centre

Comment: In that case, you'll need to take those integer indexes and convert them into a list a strings. Take a look at `Gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_cell_data_func()` or whatever the Pythonified equivalent is.

Comment: OK, then I need to do that (for position and also another attribute - club - )in the SQL command with a join to read the actual strings corresponding to the names of the positions/clubs. Trivial enough. I'm nearly ready with the first part I think. ListStore is populated and associated with a TreeView which has columns for what I need to display. The Scrollbox I've put the Treeview in is not actually displaying though, although I can see the space on the main dialog reserved for where it should be. I think it needs some meta-dialog to help it display

Comment: What code are you using to put the scrolled window in its parent? Are you sure you're calling `show_all()` on the top-level window?

Comment: pretty much the full thing is here:  http://pastebin.com/YXJnwQ1q
the window is attached to a table which is appended to a notebook for which show_all() is run

Comment: You need to show all the widgets in `table`; a simple `self.show_all()` will do the trick for everything in the window.

Comment: lines 35 and 105 have the table attach and show_all

Comment: none. all I can see is that when I stack another dialog in the same vbox it's placed half-way down so there is space being reserved for the scroll window, it's just not showing up.

Comment: I added a  tree.show_all()  after the  results_box.add(tree) and now it displays the scroll window, but only after it has got some results. As though the window can't exist while it has no trees.  The problem now is that while it runs fine the first time it crashes on the second search with gtk_scrolled_window_add: assertion 'child_widget == NULL' failed. Strange, as the tree is reset each time the search function is called.