# Python GTK - refreshing a table/scrollwindow

Tags: python, postgresql, gtk

In this simple program I'm drawing a window, adding a search box, getting a search term for the user, looking that up in a postgreSQL DB and displaying the reults. It works up to a point - when the user enters a second query.

I have tried in two different ways but each way gives a different problem. In the first way (lines 32-35 http://pastebin.com/q5bnLxaB) I'm creating the output window in the main and passing that to the search function. It crashes with gtk_scrolled_window_add: assertion 'child_widget == NULL' failed. I think because I'm adding the tree to the window when it has already been done. To fix this, I would need to reset the window somehow.

In the second way (lines 56-58) I have added the output window only in the search function so it no longer has this crashing issue. However, the window itself does not update with the results of a second or subsequent search.

Which, if either, of these methods seems the most sensible? I also need to consider that the next step is adding a clickable button beside each search term which will display extended data for each returned result.

BTW, in both cases the output window does not appear until a search is entered. It doesn't hinder functionality but it strange to me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import PixbufLoader
import urllib2
import psycopg2
import sys

class NotebookWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Rugby Database")

        #Create Application Window
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(800, 600)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)

        #Add external container (box)
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        self.add(vbox)

        #Add tabbed window
        nbook = Gtk.Notebook()
        vbox.pack_start(nbook, True, True, 0)
        nbook.show()

        #Add Main tab
        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_markup("<b><big>Main</big></b>")
        table = Gtk.Table(rows=40, columns=10)

        #Add Results field
        #results_box = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        #results_box.set_vexpand(True)
        #table.attach(results_box, 0, 1, 1, 39, xpadding=5, ypadding=5)

        #Add Search box
        entry = Gtk.Entry()
        entry.set_property("secondary-icon-stock", Gtk.STOCK_FIND)
        entry.connect("icon-press", self.on_search_button)
        #entry.connect("activate", self.on_search_enter, results_box)
        entry.connect("activate", self.on_search_enter, table)
        table.attach(entry, 0, 1, 0, 1, xpadding=5)

        nbook.append_page(table, label)


    def on_search_button(self, entry, icon, event):
        search = entry.get_text()
        print("Search for " + search)

    def on_search_enter(self, entry, table): #changed from results_box
        store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str, str)
        tree = Gtk.TreeView(store)
        ##
        results_box = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        results_box.set_vexpand(True)
        table.attach(results_box, 0, 1, 1, 39, xpadding=5, ypadding=5)
        ##
        search = entry.get_text()
        search = search.replace("'","''") #deal with apostrophes
        entry.set_text("")
        print("Search for " + search)
        result = self.lookup_player(search)
        print result
        if len(result) > 0:
           for i in range(0, len(result)):
            store.append([result[i][0],result[i][1],str(result[i][4])])
            print result[i][0],result[i][1],result[i][2],result[i][3],result[i][4],result[i][5],result[i][6],result[i][7],result[i][8]
        else:
           print "No players found"

        #Add column for last name
        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Last Name")
        column.pack_start(renderer, True)
        column.add_attribute(renderer, "text", 0)
        tree.append_column(column)

        #Add column for first name
        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("First Name")
        column.pack_start(renderer, True)
        column.add_attribute(renderer, "text", 1)
        tree.append_column(column)

        #Add column for icon
        renderer = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Show")
        column.pack_start(renderer, True)
        column.add_attribute(renderer, "stock-id", 2)
        tree.append_column(column)

        results_box.add(tree)
        table.show_all()
        tree.show_all()

    def on_click_edit(self, button):
        print("Editing Player")

    def lookup_player(self, pstring):
        try:
            con = psycopg2.connect(database='Rugby', user='postgres', password = '1234')
            cur = con.cursor()
            search = "select pl.lastname, pl.firstname, pl.height, pl.weight, to_char(pl.dob, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), cl.name, pl.injury_id, to_char(pl.suspendeduntil, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), pl.photo from player pl inner join club cl on cl.id = pl.currentclub_id where firstname ilike '%s' or lastname ilike '%s'" % (pstring, pstring)
            cur.execute(search)
            result = cur.fetchall()
            return result

        except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
            print 'Error %s' % e
            sys.exit(1)

        finally:
            if con:
                con.close()

win = NotebookWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()


Gtk.main()
```

***Note*** This is a follow-up question to 
[Python (GTK) : Can someone explain the difference between TreeStore, Listmodel and all the rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448852/python-gtk-can-someone-explain-the-difference-between-treestore-listmodel-a/28474814?noredirect=1#comment45308508_28474814)
as the original query has been answered and the scope has thus changed (BTW massive thanks to everyone who helped with that!)

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, but this might help you http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=3870

Comment: with or without a specified viewport gives the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do everything you can in `__init__()`. This includes creating the store (as an instance variable so you can use it in the search handler), creating all widgets (ScrolledWindow and TreeView) and also adding the columns to the treeview.

In the search handler you should only call `clear()` on the ListStore (to remove any old results) and then append new results to the store.

Comment: I think that would be the neatest way but the problem I face is that there doesn't seem to be any obvious way of passing back the updated store to the main (init) function once it's been updated. Is there some recognised way of assigning the result of a call to connect/activate?

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense...  It sounds like a misunderstanding of event-driven programming (the model that GTK uses): the store you update in the search handler _is_ the exact same store you (should have) created in __init__(), there's no need to "pass it back" . Is the problem still related to this question or is your table now refreshing as it should?

Comment: In that case simply calling the search function should automatically update the dialogs in the main, should it not? But in reality nothing happens, the data is sent to the search and ... that's the end of it

Comment: There are no dialogs in your code, so I don't understand what you mean. If you mean the treeview in the NoteBookWindow should get updated whenever you modify the store, then yes that should happen. If it doesn't, there's a bug somewhere in the code. If you had provided a self contained example (e.g. with fake data rows) I could have quickly tested it myself...

Comment: Sorry, bad habit of mixing up terms widgets/dialogs/controls. Tonight I'll move some code around and replace line 64 so it just works with two separate dummy lines of code depending on the value passed.

Comment: As it turns out, I had totally misused the self concept and was passing the data down when I should just have been referencing it direcly through self. in the various functions. Almost everything now works with the objects defined in __init__ and modified from the functions called.
Many thanks jku